# Did Jyn use the Force to gain access through the shield gate over Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, rogue-one, kyber-crystal

In *Rogue One*, prior to the Battle of Scarif, the Rebel infiltration unit led by Jyn Erso used a stolen cargo shuttle to land on the planet. K-2SO assumed the clearance code of the shuttle might have been logged as overdue by the Empire, but nevertheless the team decided to proceed.

> **Bodhi:** Cargo shuttle SW-0608 requesting a landing pad.
>
> **Gate Officer:** Cargo shuttle SW-0608, you're not listed on the arrival
>   schedule.
>
> **Bodhi:** Acknowledged, Gate Control. We were rerouted from Eadu flight
>   station. Transmitting clearance code now.
>
> **K-2SO:** Transmitting.

[image]

Here, during the following short period of silence, Jyn revealed the Kyber crystal necklace she had gotten from her mother, held to it, closed her eyes, and apparently meditated for a moment. Then, the gate officer let the ship pass the shield gate.

> **Gate Officer:** Cargo shuttle, SW-0608, you are cleared for entry.
>
> **Bodhi:** Yes!
>
> **K-2SO:** Impressive.

Did Jyn use the Force to manipulate the gate officer to let them pass through? Did she use the necklace somehow as a link to the Force? Could she have done it without the crystal?

Interestingly, when the necklace was given to Jyn by her mother, she said:

[image]

> **Lyra:** Trust the Force.

...Or was the access code just valid?

Comment: It was an older code, but it still checked out.

Comment: they flew casually

Comment: It seems to me like the Force in Rogue One was more of a Western religion than an Eastern one. That is, it seems like people 'prayed' to it, and sometimes either the Force answered their prayers (the Force was with them) or maybe they just got lucky (as Han might suggest).

Answer (score 3):

Jyn Erso had no force abilities whatsoever, but this doesn't mean that the force didn't help, This could have come from the force through Chirrut Imwe, none of Jyn's Family were involved in any Jedi Training, but we don't know about Jyn's Mother, obviously if she had been involved with the force, she would have tried to stop her husband from building the death star.

it was speculated that Jyn Erso's mother was originally going to be a Jedi, but it was scrapped. The code from Bohdi's stolen ship could've worked by looking at the Jedi returns, when the rebel fleet gets to the forest moon of Endor on another stolen ship from the empire, this could just be that the empire's codes still work for stolen ships, even if the empire doesn't notice.

> VADER Where is that shuttle going?
>
> PIETT  (into comlink) Shuttle Tydirium, what is your cargo and
>   destination?
>
> PILOT VOICE    (HAN)   (filtered) Parts and technical crew for the
>   forest moon.
>
> The Bridge Commander looks to Vader for a reaction.
>
> VADER Do they have a code clearance?
>
> PIETT It's an older code, sir, but it checks out. I was about to clear
>   them.
>
> Vader looks upward, as he senses Luke's presence.
>
> PIETT Shall I hold them?
>
> VADER No. Leave them to me. I will deal with them myself.
>
> PIETT  (surprised) As you wish, my lord. (to controller) Carry on.
>
> Piett nods at controller, who switches on his comlink.

Comment: `...but we don't know about Jyn's Mother, obviously if she had been involved with the force, she would have tried to stop her husband from building the death star.` - Pretty sure she did try to stop him from building the deathstar, which is why she's dead =P